# Solutions to covering exposed pin headers using a cap?

Tags: connector, protection

I have the following 6 pin headers exposed which is attached to a cable. I was wondering if there was a solution to protect the pins using a cap system like a usb stick cap. Since this will be going in my bag, I dont want to have it break/bend during travel.

[image]

Comment: What does the manufacturer have to say?

Comment: its a custom connector i made. the real one i made is this: http://www.phonerepair.us/sites/default/files/styles/xlarge_750x750/public/resized_x1017.jpg

Comment: Why not use a USB stick cap like you mention?  If the size is right, it could just stay on with friction, or if you need to you could probably figure something out with velcro tape.

Comment: If I was that concerned, I would find a small [Pelican](http://www.pelican.com/) case for the cable and its associated equipment.

Comment: FWIW, I sometimes wrap such things in either wide diameter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat-shrink_tubing or just loosely surround them with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-Tack - as far as my experience goes, both work wonders in preventing damage; YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

I would just shove it in a protective box like [this one](http://www.tedpella.com/storage-boxes-bags_html/styrene-boxes.htm#139-90):

[image]

It's inherently fragile. If you've got access to 3D parametric modelling software and a 3D printer or are willing to fiddle with castable polyurethane and modelling clay you could make a more professional looking cap, but that seems like a lot of effort unless you're planning on making lots of them.